# How to represent the value reference to my lookup data in my ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a list of (for example) countries in my database, which might have a class representation that looks like;

```
public class Country {
   public int CountryId { get; set; }
   public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have a ViewModel class that models a Student for example, and it looks like;

```
public class StudentViewModel {
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When i want to provide the Country the Student comes from, i usually include the following properties in the StudentViewModel class;

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }
public string CountryName { get; set; }
```

Now, i not quite sure if i am doing the right thing because on the client (using javascript), i have to keep the CountryId and CountryName synchronized. The reason i have done it this way for a while is because i used the CountryId property to set the initial value of the dropdownlist and CountryName to show the textual value on a different section of the same form.

I would like to know how other people are handling situations like this?

Comment: you can just use javascript to display the country name based on country id and include only country id in the viewmodel

Comment: I think that will work, however, I am beginning to think that the most robust option would be to have a StudentReadOnlyViewModel and StudentEditViewModel. That (your suggestion) will work if we always have the collection of country on the View Model or in an InitViewModel.